# How to use {{ variable }} in {% if is_exist %} in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

Like I asked in the title, I wanna do something like the below in Django.

```
{% for i in "xxxxx" %}
    {% if store{{ forloop.counter }} %}
      ...
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I pass variables named 'store1', 'store2', and 'store3' from views.py
However, an error happens saying 
"`Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from 'store{{'`"
, which seems like {{ }} can't be used inside {% %}

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in the Django template language.

A better approach would be to pass the stores to the template as a list,

```
def my_view(request):
    stores = ['store1', 'store2', ...]
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'stores': stores}
```

then loop through the list in the template:

```
{% for store in stores %}
  {{ store }}
{% endfor %}
```